# Expo Linking does not recognize provided scheme

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-linking

I have the problem that I always receive following warning while starting my application.

```
Linking requires a build-time setting `scheme` in the project's Expo config (app.config.js or app.js
on) for bare or production apps. Manually providing a `scheme` property can circumvent this warning. Using native app identifier as the scheme 'com.TravelRate'. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/
```

In my app.json I have it configured like this:

```
 "expo": {
    "name": "TravelRate",
    "slug": "TravelRate",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "scheme": "com.travelrate",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
```

As you can see I have provided a scheme, but its still showing me the warning even after prebuild.

I tried already alot of different names, but nothing worked